# Install J on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I am fairly new to ubuntu and I still have trouble installing some things. I have to use a language called J for an assignment. I have downloaded the necessary files and I am given an install page. However I do not understand what to do. Can someone please explain?

http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/System/Installation/J803

Comment: That j803 version is stale. Instead, see code.jsoftware.com/wiki/System/Installation and the links from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you explained what your not understanding. The instructions on the site seem pretty clear, and since we don't know if there's something specific you want to achieve, it's hard to add to that.

Based on these instruction, it should be as simple as:

```
wget http://www.jsoftware.com/download/j803/install/j803_linux64.tar.gz
tar xzf j803_linux64.tar.gz
*j803/jconsole.sh
```

But that didn't work, or what is the question at hand?

Comment: To be completely honest I didn't know that ./jconsole.sh worked

Comment: So I tried this, updating with 805 rather than 803.  Everything worked except the very last command, got the error, `sudo: *j805/jconsole.sh: command not found` any idea why?

Comment: ... figured it out immediately, did *805 instead of *j805, they must have re-named things.